# I need helping adding two different rows(with same columns) to the same datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, row, datagridviewcolumn

Working on a windows form application that reads in data from csv files and adds the data to a Datagridview. I ran into an issue with all of the rows being added to the datable and being displayed on the datagridview. The datagridview displays the datarows from the first two if conditions and OneRow if condition only. It will not add the rows from the twoRow if condition if the datable and datagridview rows are populated with the OneRow if condition rows. But i want the rows from both OneRow and TwoRow to be displyed. Also the rows from TwoRow do populate the datatable and datagridview when I comment(/**/) out the OneRow if condition. But I need both to populate the table. Thanks in advance!

```
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("Time");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("Serial");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("Type");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("level");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("price");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add(" Limit");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("last Limit");
        Construct.MainDataTable.Columns.Add("Data");
        ..........................
    ...............................................
        DataRow oneRow = Construct.MainDataTable.NewRow();
        DataRow twoRow = Construct.MainDataTable.NewRow();
        dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        if (line.Split(',')[2].Equals("Time"))
        {
         time = line.Split(',')[3];
         date = line.Split(',')[1];
         }
        if (line.Split(',')[2].Equals("Level"))
        {
         level = line.Split(',')[3];

         }
        //OneROw(IF condition)
        if ((Convert.ToDecimal(line.Split(',')[8])) < (Convert.ToDecimal     (line.Split(',')[12]))) 
        {

          type = line.Split(',')[1];
          serial = line.Split(',')[7];
          price = line.Split(',')[3];
          Limit = line.Split(',')[8];
          lastLimit = line.Split(',')[10];
          Data = line.Split(',')[12];

          oneRow["Date"] = date;
          oneRow["Time"] = time;
          oneRow["Serial"] = serial;
          oneRow["Type"] = type;
          oneRow["level"] = level;
          oneRow["price"] = price;
          oneRow[" Limit"] = Limit;
          oneRow["last Limit"] = lastlimit;
          oneRow["Data"] = Data;
          Construct.MainDataTable.Rows.Add(oneRow);
         }  
       //TwoROw(IF condition)                             
        if ((line.Contains('"')) && ((line.Contains("NG"))))
        {
          price = line.Split(',')[3];
          type = line.Split(',')[1];
          serial = line.Split(',')[7];
          Limit = line.Split('"')[7];
          var valLimit = Limit.Split(',').Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a, 16));
          var limitJoin = String.Join(",", valLimit);
          lastlimit = line.Split('"')[1];
          var vallastLimit = lastlimit.Split(',').Select(d => Convert.ToInt32(d, 16));
          var lastJoin = String.Join(",", vallastLimit);
          Data = line.Split('"')[5];
          var valDatas = Data.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s, 16));
          var dataJoin = String.Join(",", valDatas);
          twoRow["Date"] = date;
          twoRow["Time"] = time;
          twoRow["Serial"] = serial;
          twoRow["Type"] = type;
          twoRow["level"] = level;
          twoRow["price"] = price;
          twoRow["Limit"] = limitJoin;
          twoRow["last Limit"] = lastJoin;
          twoRow["Data"] = dataJoin;
          Construct.MainDataTable.Rows.Add(twoRow);
          }
         dataGridView2.DataSource = Construct.MainDataTable;
```

Comment: You should really save the result of `Split(',')` into a variable rather than splitting the line into an array on just about every line!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't add a comment because I don't have enough karma so I ask my questions here: So, if I understood your problem you can't add data from one .csv file if it have more then one row? Why are you using 2 different if conditions for row in .csv file?

If you have empty data in row never mind you can still place them to your DataTable column, so you can use loop to add data from .csv to your DataTable. Try some thing like this:

```
    public static DataTable CsvToDataTable(string csv)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string[] lines = csv.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Regex onlyDeimiterComma = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            string[] cells = onlyDeimiterComma.Split(lines[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                { 
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cells[j], typeof(DateTime));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cells[j]);
                    }                   
                }
                else
                {
                    row[j] = cells[j];
                }
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Just call this method anywhere in your code and give it string read from your .csv file.
You can try to compile this code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2LDLV2) and see how it works on .csv data with different data (empty columns, quoted text, quoted commas)

**UPD:** If you need to fill DataTable from two different .csv files you can still use code above. Just call it twice for both files and then Merge two DataTable, like this:

```
DataTable dt = CsvToDataTable(csvFileOne);
DataTable dtTwo = CsvToDataTable(csvFileTwo);
dt.Merge(dtTwo);
```